# Font in WPF application looks different in notepad or any other application

Tags: wpf, fonts

I have otf font called "Houschka Rounded". In notepad, word or any WinForms app it looks like this:

[image] - **this is ok**

Code:

```
<TextBox Text="asdf www w er AAs" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Houschka Rounded" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="317" />
```

In WPF 4.0 it looks like this:

[image] - **this is bad**

Anyone know why it's happening?

Comment: Whats your code for the textbox look like?
How about the style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out that otf font has featureas which can change the look of font. In my case I set ContextualAlternates=false.

```
<TextBox FontFamily="Houschka Rounded" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="317">
    <Run Typography.ContextualAlternates="False" >
        asdf www w er AAs
    </Run>
</TextBlock>
```

For details see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745109.aspx